# Deploying back-end and front-end on AWS

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-rds

I have a full-stack application with Node and express for the back-end (with Postgres in a AWS RDS created already) and Angular for the front-end.

Now, when running locally in development I have the back-end listening to port 3000 and conected a Pool client with a Postgres DB in AWS RDS. Separately, I have my front-end listenting to port 4200.

When running the server and the angular in these two different ports and opening my browser everything works fine.

Now my questions are about how to deploy this same structure in AWS all together.

Shall I deploy in AWS the back-end and front-end listening to these two different ports (as deployment) or they should listen to the same one and add a proxy server like Ngnix like I have been reading?

In the last case, how?

Comment: You can package the node in a container and deploy it as ECS Service and expose it over application load balancer(ALB). Frontend if its static HTML can go in S3 and exposed via cloudfront. You wont need NGinx as ALB would help in routing.

Comment: Thank you. Any links or documentation to learn how to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecs-nodejs-microservices

Comment: Very difficult to follow and understand... I don't know how to apply it with my app. It is using also docker for what I can see... Is it not possible to do what I asked without using docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a simple setup, and you always deploy frontend and backend at the same time, one option would be: just let you express backend also serve your static Angular files.

This avoids any unnecessary complexity and components.

So, you have both frontend and backend exposed at the same port. Maybe all your backend APIs are listening under the `/api` route. Everything else is served statically, with a fallback to `index.html` for client-side routing.

By having frontend and backend on the same origin (host:port), you also avoid any CORS issues.

Comment: Thanks ! I know that options but I would like to know how to deploy separately as well. I have also read that it is a good approach. Could I do it without the use of docker containers or Nginx?

Comment: Whether something is a good approach or not really depends on the circumstances. If in doubt, prefer the simpler solution, that _you_ can understand and maintain. Of course, if you do deploy them independently, FE and BE will be probably on different hosts altogether. You probably do not need a gateway/proxy. Just try what works for you. Do not overcomplicate from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will try both approach to learn and see what is more convinient